# UE4 project not correctly imported

Tags: unreal-engine4

I just got a new laptop and installed the unreal engine. When I download my project from Github and imported it to unreal, it is corrupted (as the picture shows below, the cubes are not showing but the shadows, that custom actors and characters are not showing too).

When I go back to my original machine, the project works well and has no problem. I have tried redownloading the project and the problem still exists. However, when I create a new template, it is fine without the same problem.

I don't know what is wrong with the project or the engine that caused this problem, I am sure both machines runs the same code and have the same version of the unreal engine.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The version control software that I use, "sourcetree", defaults me to checkout on a branch when I clone the repo. This caused me to run the branch instead of the master. I have to clone the master branch back on my machine to make it work.